# Как задать изображение и цвета блока одновременно (CSS)?

Tags: css

Как задать блоку изображение, а слоем выше цвет?

Пробую следующие варианты, но цвет становится слоем ниже изображения (нужно наоборот):

```
background: #000 url(image.jpg);
background: url(image.jpg) #000;
```

Comment: Если цвет будет выше, то картинки видно не будет, или вы хотите полупрозрачный цвет наложить?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин разумеется полупрозрачным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методом научного google-тыка разобрался.

Вместо базового `#fff` принимает свойство в формате градиента:

```
background: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff), url(/assets/templates/default/images/background-big-1.jpg);
```

Comment: Отлично. А я уже хотел SVG решение писать, но теперь не буду.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать `background-color` и `background-image`. Если изображение меньше элемента, надо использовать `background-position`, чтобы поместить куда необходимо. Чтобы картинка не повторялась и не заместила весь фон, нужно использовать `background-repeat`:

```
background-color: #000;
background-image: url(image.jpg);
background-position: right; /*Например справа размещаем картинку*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Компактная запись:

```
background: #000 url(image.jpg) right no-repeat;
```

Если использовать два свойства `background`, то первое описанное будет игнорироваться:

```
background: #000; /* Игнорируется */
background: url(image.jpg) right no-repeat;
```